# How to do geocoding offline in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to take a properly formatted address and geocode it, without using an online geocoder?
I have a file with several thousand address and would like to geocode them, but due to api restrictions on request velocity/limits... it is very inconvenient to use online sources

I've looked into several geocoding libraries, but they all seem to use online sources. Geonames was the most promising, but it seems to be made for python 2

**Note:** There exists a post [titled similarly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859223/how-to-do-geocoding-offline-in-python), but it was a mislabeled POI question and answered accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the python library [geocoder](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geocoder) and use your own instance of the [Open Street Maps Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).

Please check the [Nominatim Install Guide](https://github.com/openstreetmap/Nominatim/blob/master/docs/Installation.md) on how to install nominatim.